# How to display plain text using QMessageBox?

Tags: qt, qmessagebox

I need to display an HTML text:

```
QString text="<b>Hello</b>";
QMessageBox::information(this,"info", text);
```

The text is displayed as bold "Hello". How to display it as it is, i.e.,

```
<b>Hello</b>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the method [`toHtmlEscaped()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#toHtmlEscaped) of [`QString`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html):

```
QString text="<b>Hello</b>";
QMessageBox::information(this, "info", text.toHtmlEscaped());
```